# SCNTransaction color fade?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am trying to fade my nodes color smoothly but can't seem to get SCNTransaction to work properly. I want to slowly transition from one color to another.

```
    let defaultMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    defaultMaterial.diffuse.contents = randomColor()
    defaultMaterial.specular.contents = randomColor()
    defaultMaterial.emission.contents = randomColor()

    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 2.0
    emptyLeftSquare.firstMaterial? = defaultMaterial
    emptyRightSquare.firstMaterial? = defaultMaterial
    emptyUpSquare.firstMaterial? = defaultMaterial
    emptyDownSquare.firstMaterial? = defaultMaterial
    emptyBottomRightLink.firstMaterial? = defaultMaterial
    emptyBottomLeftLink.firstMaterial? = defaultMaterial
    emptyTopLeftLink.firstMaterial? = defaultMaterial
    emptyTopRightLink.firstMaterial? = defaultMaterial
    SCNTransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are setting the `defaultMaterial` just once, before the transaction begins and using the same value repeatedly for the duration of the animation. Since there is no change after the initial value is set, you are not seeing any color changes.

If you set the color again within the `transaction`, you should be fine.  Or if you want the colors to be different for each of the squares and links, then refactor the initial `defaultMaterial` setup to a method and reuse that.